# Error shows " Could not connect to the target "

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, synchronization

I want to sync my local database to hosted database. I make a connection source database to 'current connection' with database 'aks' and target database with as you see in attached pic. Kindly help me to get rid of this error.

[image: attached pic]

Comment: Try to put the ip of the remote server instead of its name. Also check if it is configured to accept connection from remote hosts.

Comment: 31.170.164.92 its my website ip address. I put it but no way. How to check configuration to accept connection?

Comment: i tell you my localhost phpmyadmin version is 3.5.1 but hosted phpmyadmin version is 3.5.2.2 which no have synchronize tab. Is it make to synchronize error?

Comment: Is this the address of aks.zz.mu? To test it try to connect to it via terminal and see what you get. Or you can contact who hosts the server for further information.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is just a tool. What you are doing is enabling a sync between the two MySQL servers. Is the ip you gave the ip of the server where MySQL runs?

Comment: yes, aks.zz.mu is my website address. I connect it but no way.

Comment: 31.170.164.92 this ip is for my web named aks.zz.mu.

Comment: yes, i want to sync two MySQL database.

Comment: I want to sync two database by any method. You can also suggest me another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old, unsupported version of phpMyAdmin. The Synchronize feature was removed because of difficulties such as this.

What's likely happening is that your remote server, `aks.zz.mu`, probably isn't allowing external connections. Many MySQL instances don't, either by restricting permissions, not listening for external connections, or by being blocked by a firewall -- this is a security precaution. Are you sure your host allows this and that your user `u269500864_root` is authorized for connections from the remote IP address?